# Finding combination of bacteria that represents maximal functions encoded by them

Tags: optimization, combinatorics

I have the following data where rows represent functions and columns represent bacteria. I have 18 bacteria with a total of 160 functions (all funcitons are present in at least one bacteria). I want to find the best combination of bacterial strains that can maximally represent the functions. Appreciate any lead.

[image]